# How to sort and filter of an array based on another array?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, filter

How can I filter and sort the `listOfFruits` according to a different country and store it into `listOfFilterAndSortedFruits?`

**For example:**
If I choose `Canada` with `listOfFruit`: `["Cherries", "Peer", "Cherries", "Apple"]` and the `listOfFilterAndSortedFruits` will be

```
var listOfFilterAndSortedFruits:[Fruit] = [
    Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy"),
    Fruit(name: "Peer", taste: "Sweat"),
    Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy"),
    Fruit(name: "Apple", taste: "Sweat")
]
```

```swift
class Fruit {
    var name: String
    var taste: String

    init(name: String, taste: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste
    }
}

class Country {
    var name: String
    var listOfFruit: [String]

    init(name: String, listOfFruit: [String]) {
        self.name = name
        self.listOfFruit = listOfFruit
    }
}

var listOfFruits:[Fruit] = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple", taste: "Sweat"),
    Fruit(name: "Orange", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy"),
    Fruit(name: "Banana", taste: "Sweet"),
    Fruit(name: "Carambola", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Peer", taste: "Sweat"),
]

var listOfCountries:[Country] = [
    Country(name: "USA", listOfFruit: ["Apple", "Orange", "Cherries"]),
    Country(name: "Brazil", listOfFruit: ["Orange", "Banana", "Peer", "Carambola"]),
    Country(name: "Canada", listOfFruit: ["Cherries", "Peer", "Cherries", "Apple"]),
]

let listOFFruitInCanada = ["Cherries", "Peer", "Cherries", "Apple"]
var listOfFilterAndSortedFruits = [Fruit]()
```

Comment: can you please make it clear

Comment: Why not just have a `Fruit` array instead of `String` array in `listofCountries`.

Comment: Change `var listOfFruit: [String]` to `var listOfFruit: [Fruit]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an array of fruits:

```
let listOfFruits = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple", taste: "Sweet"),
    Fruit(name: "Orange", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy"),
    Fruit(name: "Banana", taste: "Sweet"),
    Fruit(name: "Carambola", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Pear", taste: "Sweet"),
]
```

But that is an inefficient structure, because any time you want to look up a fruit in that array, you have to scan through them.

Instead, you can use a dictionary.

For example, you might create one from `listOfFruits`:

```
let fruitDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: listOfFruits) { $0.name }
```

Or, if this `listOfFruits` is just for lookup purposes, you might just initially define it as a dictionary, and bypass this “convert array to dictionary” step.

Regardless, given an array of Canadian fruit names:

```
let listOfFruitNamesInCanada = ["Cherries", "Pear", "Cherries", "Apple"]
```

If you want a corresponding array of `Fruit` objects, you can now look up the `Fruit` instances in the dictionary:

```
let listOfFruitsInCanada = listOfFruitNamesInCanada.compactMap { fruitDictionary[$0] }
```

Resulting in:

```
[
    [Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy")], 
    [Fruit(name: "Pear", taste: "Sweet")], 
    [Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy")], 
    [Fruit(name: "Apple", taste: "Sweet")]
]
```

The key take-away is that I’m not scanning through the array with `listOfFruits.first(where: ...)` (because that has to rescan through the array for each fruit we’re searching for, with a resulting complexity of `O(n)`). Instead, I’m using a dictionary, `fruitDictionary[...]` (in which we can immediately find the desired `Fruit` object, with `O(1)` complexity).

---

Unrelated, but you might consider using `struct` types:

```
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let taste: String
}

struct Country {
    let name: String
    let listOfFruit: [String]
}
```

You can use your `class` reference types, if you really want, but nowadays we tend to use `struct` value types.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`compactMap(_:)`** to map the each name `String` `listOFFruitInCanada` to `Fruit` object in `listOfFruits` using **`first(where:)`**, i.e.

```
var listOfFilterAndSortedFruits = listOFFruitInCanada.compactMap({ (name) -> Fruit? in
    listOfFruits.first(where: { $0.name == name })
})
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great. Do accept(tick on left) if the answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to get the sorted list of fruits for the given country name, if this is the case then below code will serve your purpose.

**getSortedFriutListForCountry** method will give the sorted list of fruits for the country name if the country with that name exists.

```
var listOfFruits:[Fruit] = [
    Fruit(name: "Apple", taste: "Sweat"),
    Fruit(name: "Orange", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Cherries", taste: "Juicy"),
    Fruit(name: "Banana", taste: "Sweet"),
    Fruit(name: "Carambola", taste: "Tart"),
    Fruit(name: "Peer", taste: "Sweat"),
]

var listOfCountries:[Country] = [
    Country(name: "USA", listOfFruit: ["Apple", "Orange", "Cherries"]),
    Country(name: "Brazil", listOfFruit: ["Orange", "Banana", "Peer", "Carambola"]),
    Country(name: "Canada", listOfFruit: ["Cherries", "Peer", "Cherries", "Apple"]),
]

func getSortedFriutListForCountry(_ countryName: String) -> [Fruit] {
    let fruitNames = listOfCountries.first(where: { $0.name == countryName })?.listOfFruit
    return listOfFruits.filter { fruitNames?.contains($0.name) ?? false }.sorted { f1, f2 in
        f1.name < f2.name
    }
}
```